# Expected number of multinomial samples to cover a multiset

Tags: probability, expected-value, multinomial-distribution, stopping-time

Consider a multinomial distribution $[p_1, \ldots, p_n]$ and a collection of counts $[a_1, \ldots, a_n]$. I would like to know the expected number of multinomial samples needed until every element $i$ has been sampled at least $a_i$ times.

More formally let
$$
X_1, X_2, \ldots \sim \operatorname{Multinomial}([p_1, ..., p_n]) \\
C_i^j = \sum_{i' \le i} \boldsymbol{1}_{X_{i'} = j} \\
M = \min \{i: \forall j \le n, C_i^j \ge a_j\}
$$
and I would like to know $\mathbb E [M]$.

This isn't quite the [negative multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_multinomial_distribution) since I want all values to reach a threshold rather than just the first. It feels like it should have closed form expectation but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: For the case where $p_1=p_2=...=p_n$, this is the double dixie cup problem.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly the name I needed! It appears to have been generalized to my case with https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3626

Comment: Ah, not quite exactly my case in the arxiv paper.  Specifically they allow unequal probabilities but assume $a_1 = a_2 = \ldots = a_n = N$